# How do I run rubymine as a regular user?

Tags: ruby

I installed rubymine on ubuntu as instructed on their site (extract and run a bash script from bin).

Currently, when I want to run the application I need to run this script from terminal as super user.

What to do in order to run it like every normal app?

I also noticed that auto completion does not work on rubymine, do you know what cause that?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is not the intended behavior. I suggest [filing this as a bug on RubyMines bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/dashboard/RUBY#tab=0)